# How to change the title of a Wordpress author archive feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, filter, title, archive

I have a wordpress site and have used this URL to generate a feed of one author's posts:

http://www.my-awesome-site.com/author/joe/feed/

The automatically generated title of this feed is "My Awesome Site >> Joe"

Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the feed title to something like "Joe Smith's Awesome Words of Wisdom."

I can't quite figure out where the feed title is generated, and what hook i might use to filter it. Any thoughts?

Edit: Wow this was a pain. Didn't realize for a while that WP caches feeds. I tried a number of approaches, but in the end I just hacked core, changing the title tag in feed-rss.php, feed-rss2.php, feed-atom.php, and feed-rdf.php to

```
<title><?php
    if (is_author('joe')) {
        echo "Joe Smith's Awesome Words of Wisdom";
    } else {
        bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); 
    }
?></title>
```

Better suggestions still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for the same kind of thing without using a plugin. Wordpress has two filters for you to use: `wp_title` and `document_title_parts`:

**METHOD 1: Using `wp_title`**:

Note that this method will still append the site description at the end of the `<title>` tag.

```
function custom_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
  if (is_author()) {
    $author = array(
      'user_firstname' => get_the_author_meta('user_firstname'),
      'user_lastname' => get_the_author_meta('user_lastname')
    );
    $title = $author['user_firstname'] . ' ' . $author['user_lastname'] . ' Awesome Words of Wisdom.'; 
  } 
  return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_wp_title', 100, 2 );
```

**METHOD 2: Using `document_title_parts`**:

```
function custom_wp_title($title){

    if(is_author()){ 
      $author = array(
        'user_firstname' => get_the_author_meta('user_firstname'),
        'user_lastname' => get_the_author_meta('user_lastname')
      );
      $title['title'] = $author['user_firstname'] . ' ' . $author['user_lastname'] . ' Awesome Words of Wisdom.';

      /* Uncomment this if you 
      ** want to remove the site 
      ** description at the end of the title:
         $title['site'] = ''; 
      **
      **/
    }

    return $title; 
}
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'custom_wp_title', 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the wordpress plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/

This allows you to change all SEO related properties (meta-tags, descriptions, titles etc...)

In the options there is a section that allows you to change titles for specific page and post types.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I use All-in-one, but it doesn't go so far as allowing you to change an author feed title. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ahh, Right you are, I assumed that the categories title tag would have done that but apparently not.